# How to make comma separated string in SQL on the base of another column

Tags: sql

Suppose I have data in table:

```
select * from [dbo].[EmployeeWorkLocations] order by employeeid
```

```
WLId    EmployeeId  WLStateId
28  1   2
29  1   1
30  1   3
73  1   3
81  2   1
82  2   2
67  2   2
69  2   3
70  2   2
5   5   1
6   5   2
7   5   3
91  6   1
92  6   2
83  6   1
90  6   2
88  6   2
26  6   3
93  7   1
94  7   2
95  7   4
27  8   3
```

```
select * from [dbo].[WorkLocation]
```

```
Id  State
1   Delhi
2   Orissa
3   Mumbai
4   Pune
```

My expected output is:

```
EmployeeId  State
1   Orissa, Delhi, Mumbai, Mumbai
2   Delhi, Orissa, Orissa, Mumbai, Orissa
5   Delhi, Orissa, Mumbai
6   Delhi, Orissa, Delhi, Orissa, Orissa, Mumbai
7   Delhi, Orissa, Pune
8   Mumbai
```

How can I make comma separated string in SQL on the base of another column?

Comment: Please add [a tag for the DBMS implementation (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, etc.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql#:~:text=a%20tag%20for%20the%20DBMS%20implementation%20(e.g.%20MySQL%2C%20PostgreSQL%2C%20Oracle%2C%20MS%20SQL%20Server%2C%20IBM%20DB2%2C%20etc.)) you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I find Below SQL Query is very useful and easy to implement:

```
SELECT  T1.EmployeeId, STRING_AGG(T2.State , ', ') AS [State]
FROM [dbo].[EmployeeWorkLocations] T1 
INNER JOIN [dbo].[WorkLocation] T2 ON T1.WLStateId = T2.ID 
GROUP BY T1.Employee
```

Comment: please try to explain the answer, Don't just use AI tools to copy paste the answer :)

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least let OP and the rest of us know which dbms this is for.

Comment: I have tried this SQL Query in MS-SQL Server Version 19.1